# Use Wordpress Filter to modify value of wp_head output?

Tags: wordpress

I have just started with Worpdress, and see what when creating a custom theme there is an annoying margin at the top of the page, and that is caused by the content output by the wp_head function. Since I need to learn how to use filters, I thought I would use a filter to remove the css for the html and body tags from the wp_head functions.

The question is, how do I do that? Inside the function I use for a filter, how I am able to access the values for the css written out for the html tag in the wp_head function? Have searched by have found no good explanation for this.

Comment: `wp_head()` happens inside the `<head>` element, so it shouldn't produce any visible spaces. Also, `wp_head` is an action, not a filter, so you can't filter the output produced by `wp_head()` directly.

Comment: I was talking about the margins and paddings for the html and body elements. Are there any other ways of removing them elegantly in a custom theme?

Comment: You can do whatever you want in your custom theme. But you can't easily filter the output of `wp_head`

Comment: WorpDress, I love it! On-topic: Better find the part that causes the space. I can't believe `wp_head` is causing it.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove (and add) classes to the `<body>` tag as long as the theme is using [`<?php body_class(); ?>`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/body_class/)

There is a [`body_class`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/body_class/) filter hook at the [end of `get_body_class()` in *includes/post-template.php*](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.8/src/wp-includes/post-template.php#L770)

---

### From Codex

> `apply_filters( 'body_class', array $classes, array $class )`
>   Filters the list of CSS body classes for the current post or page.

[Remove a class from the body_class array](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/body_class/#comment-1680):

```
add_filter( 'body_class', function( $classes ) {
    if ( isset( $classes['class-to-remove'] ) ) {
        unset( $classes['class-to-remove'] );
    }
    return $classes;
} );
```

[Add specific CSS class by filter:](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/body_class/#comment-1681)

```
add_filter( 'body_class', function( $classes ) {
    return array_merge( $classes, array( 'class-name' ) );
} );
```

---

### Styesheets

To remove style sheets, as long as they are registered properly,

```
function dequeue_some_css() {
  wp_dequeue_style('some-css');
  wp_deregister_style('some-css');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','dequeue_some_css', 100);
```

Look into [`wp_dequeue_style`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dequeue_style) and [`wp_deregister_style`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_deregister_style)

---

For adding your own style sheets, see [`wp_enqueue_style`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/) and [`wp_register_style`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_style).